# Is it possible to create an "archer caster" who can infuse their arrows with magic elements?

Tags: character-creation, magic, ranged-attack, 13th-age

I was wondering if it's possible to create an archer with the ability to infuse their arrows with magic elements to make different types of arrows (fire arrow, electric arrow, etc.) and use them in combat for additional effect. Pretty much like in Zelda games, with all the different lootable arrows, but with magic.

Right now, I'm playing *13th Age* with some friends, and I would like to know if this kind of gameplay is possible for a future campaign.

Answer (score 2):

With GM permission, you could use something from a third party publisher Kobold Press. They have a New Paths compendium, which is originally intended for Pathfinder, but on [this page on their site](https://koboldpress.com/new-paths-ranger-talents-for-13th-age/) they state that it could be compatible with 13th Age, and give an example of being able to infuse arrows:

> **Enchanted Arrows**
>
> You know a small number of words of power that you can use to infuse your arrows with magical energy. As a quick action, you may change your arrows’ damage type to fire, cold, lightning, thunder, poison or acid until the end of the encounter or you change them again. If you have the Ranger ex Cathedral Talent, you may choose holy damage as well. The arrows’ damage does not increase but you can use it to exploit vulnerabilities and avoid resistances.
>
> *Adventurer*: Once per round, you deal extra damage to the target and all adjacent enemies equal to your Intelligence modifier on a natural even hit with an enchanted arrow. You may also cause such an arrow to explode on command for a non-combative purpose (creating illumination, mimicking a signal flare, etc)
>
> *Champion*: Once per day, you may loose an arrow of finding. The arrow will hit its target without error ignoring distance, resistances, obstructions or even differing planes of existence. In order to loose the arrow of finding, you must be able to tie something to the arrow that represents the target (some blood, a hair, a bit of fabric, etc). If you use this ability to return an arrow that the target used to attack you, it deals double damage.
>
> *Epic*: Once per day, when you hit a target with an arrow you may immediately teleport to your target’s location. You may even be “riding” the arrow, perhaps by infusing your whole essence into it when you let it go.